# Is there a free way to utilise Amazon API without AWS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm creating a project that needs to be able to grab products with JS and find the name of the product, average review, and import the main image.

I realize that Amazon has an API for this but is there a way I can get this without paying for AWS?

On GitHub, I only found Python that could do this for me.  Any JS ways?

Comment: If the python was just making a web service call you can do that in js. If it wasn't, explain how the python code worked.

Comment: Did you read the part about how *"This license does not include any resale or commercial use of any Amazon Service, or its contents; any collection and use of any product listings, descriptions, or prices; any derivative use of any Amazon Service or its contents; any downloading, copying, or other use of account information for the benefit of any third party; or any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools"* from the [Amazon.com Conditions of Use](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=508088)?  Just checking.

Comment: Thank you.  I was aware of that.

Comment: This isn't a breech of any amazon contract. He is talking about PA-API, not amazon.com website. These are two different terms and conditions. It looks like no one actually gave a correct answer to this legit question. @card100, the answer is yes! You have to apply through Amazon's associate program. It is misleading, but once you create an associate account, you will then have the ability to apply for their advertising API (PA-API). Once approved you will receive a token and secret to make requests to parse amazon product images, titles, descriptions, urls, ect

Comment: @portfoliobuilder I managed to get an associate account early in 2018 (or mid 2018), and I didn't need to get approved. I currently ran into an issue of needing to get a new token and now I need to get my account approved. When did this change?

Comment: @AChildofGod Sorry for the late response, but this changed third quarter of 2018. You now need to be approved, and if you do not do any sales in the first few weeks they will remove your account completely and then you have to start all over again. It is a real pain. The latest rule changes messed everything up, because you can no longer use their API for mobile apps either. They won't allow this. Personally, I gave up on PA-API and moved on to Best Buy. Better customer service, allows mobile apps, and they show an interest in what you are building.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could do it in node.js with an http request to the page, then screen scrape the page for information.  I'm sure they have standard css selectors, so you just look for those with regular expressions and get their values.

The code would look something like this (I haven't tested this code, but riffed on David Walsh's work here: https://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request)

```
var http = require('http');

function getAmazonPageContent(callback) {

return http.get({
    host: 'www.amazon.com',
    path: '/What-Node-Brett-McLaughlin-ebook/dp/B005ISQ7JC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1492187829&sr=8-1&keywords=node.js'
}, function(response) {
    // Continuously update stream with data
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {

        // Data reception is done, do whatever with it!
        callback(body);
    });
});

}
```

Comment: This is a clear violation of the amazon.com [Conditions of Use](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=508088).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you should post that on the original question as well. The  asker may not be aware of it.

Comment: That's difficult to imagine, but maybe you're right.  Commented accordingly.

Comment: A lot of times, people are more concerned with 'is it possible' than 'will they let me' when trying to start a business idea with nothing more than the idea and a laptop.